# polynomials invariant under an operator

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Consider the polynomial vector space $P_k^n = \{ p \in \mathbb{Q}[u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k] \;\; | \;\; p \;\text{homogeneous of degree}\;n \}$ and the operator $\text{push}: P_k^n \to P_k^n, \; \text{push}(p)(u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k) = p(-u_1-u_2-\cdots-u_k, u_1,u_2,...,u_{k-1})$. It can be shown that applying $\text{push}$ to a polynomial $k+1$ times returns itself, i.e. $\text{push}^{\circ(k+1)}(p) = p$. Let $V_k^n = \{ p \in P_k^n \;\; | \;\; \text{push}(p) = p \}$ be the "push-invariant" subspace of $P_k^n$. What is the dimension of $V_k^n$ and can one even explicitly write down its basis elements?

Here is my current attempt: any $p(u_1,...,u_k) \in V_k^n$ can also be written as $F(u_1,...,u_k,-u_1-u_2-\cdots-u_k)$, where $F \in P_{k+1}^n$ is invariant under the action of the cyclic group $<(1\;2\;\cdots\;k+1)>$, i.e. $F(u_1,u_2,...,u_{k+1}) = F(u_2,u_3,...,u_{k+1}, u_1) = \cdots = F(u_{k+1},u_1,...,u_k)$. Thus, $V_k^n$ is isomorphic to the vector space $\{ F(u_1,u_2,...,u_{k+1}) \in P_{k+1}^n \;\; | \;\; (1\;2\;\cdots\;k+1) \cdot F = F \}$ quotiented by the equivalence relation $u_1 + u_2 + \cdots + u_{k+1} \sim 0$. I am able to write down a basis of $\{ F \in P_{k+1}^n \;\; | \;\; (1\;2\;\cdots\;k+1) \cdot F = F \}$ in terms of lyndon words (a lyndon word is the smallest word in lexicographic order among all its rotations), but then there is still that equivalence relation to deal with, which interacts with the basis elements in a way I don't know.

For example, when $k=n=2$, $V_2^2 \simeq \{ F \in P_3^2 \;\; | \;\; (1\;2\;\cdots\;k+1) \cdot F = F \} \>/\> \{u_1 + u_2 + u_3 \sim 0\}$. $\{ F \in P_3^2 \;\; | \;\; (1\;2\;\cdots\;k+1) \cdot F = F \}$ has a basis $\{ u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2,\; u_1u_2 + u_2u_3 + u_3u_1  \}$. With the equivalence relation, it turns out that $u_1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2 \sim -2(u_1u_2 + u_2u_3 + u_3u_1)$, so $V_2^2$ only has dimension $1$. I don't know the situation for general k and n.

I believe there are different approaches that can solve this problem more elegantly. If anyone knows one, please let me know, thank you!